# How can a radio button trigger a counter and print output to the viewer's box?

Tags: javascript, var

How can I pass a javascript variable into the text value box below four radio buttons when one of them is selected.

//something like

```
var new ="somethign";
<a href="javascript:insertText(' var new ' ,'user_location');" 
onClick="void(0)">Insert 'Hello'</a>
```

...so that when they click it, the counter and or a message is displayed in an empty form box...?

I want to output the contents of the variable. into a form-field entry type of box.

Comment: Given that your HTML displays a link saying "Insert 'Hello'", and you want yo insert the text "Somethign [sic]" (and presumably the location, from somewhere else), this question is a little confusing.

Comment: Agreed. To achieve what you are trying to do; you need to use <div name = "whatever" id = "blah">Foobar</div>. Thats roughly the HTML side. Then javascript you use a function like getobjectfromelementid("your id").another call. That is how to roughly do it in suedo code.

Answer (score 0):

Using [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) you could do something like this:

from your question i'm not getting much of idea.but if you want to put some text to div on click of radio button then may be try in this way:

```
<script>
 $(document).ready(function(){
     $('input[type=radio]').click(function() {
         $('#viewer').html($(this).val());
     });
 });
   </script>
<input type='radio' name ="r"value="something1">1
<input type='radio'name ="r" value="something2">2
<input type='radio' name ="r"value="something3">3
<input type='radio'name ="r" value="something4">4
<div id="viewer" ></>
```